# Security PATCH SUPEE-10975 Installation Issues in Config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, patches, ce-1.9.1.0, supee-10975

`[test_servert@AMER14VMW03 htdocs]$ bash ./PATCH_SUPEE-10975_CE_v1.9.1.1_v1-2018-11-27-09-18-02.sh`

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

**ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.**

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Template/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Zend.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Image/Rest/Admin/V1.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 428 (offset 3 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 452 (offset 3 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6.1.2-1.6.0.6.1.3.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer/Address.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/sql/payment_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.1.1-1.6.0.0.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Block/Send.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/files.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/sharing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_Captcha.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Wishlist.csv
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.map
```

Comment: I have the same flaw. I have all the previous patches set except for php 7.0.
Returning to the "original" version of config.xml has not solved the problem.
How can I solve it? Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully. patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Template/Edit.php patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143533)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143533)

Comment: I've followed these steps.!
1) Take a backup of current config.xml and replace the same with original file.
2) Open the Patch file. There you can find from what version of Mage_Core version is changing to what. 
3) Copy the old Mage_Core version whcih you found on step 2 and update that in config.xml.
Now, Install the patch again.
Compare the config.xml with your backup file and update the changes occured while installing other patches (if any).

Thats it.! Its applied for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you attach the contents of the patch file and the contents of the Get the original file contents of the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml`.

All you have to check in the patch file about what changes are being done to this file. Also, check what is expected at the line 28 of the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml`.

---

Alternatively, what you can do is get the file contents of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` for your magento version   from Magento site and copy those contents to your code repository.

At times, formatting issues of the core files ( or manual changes ) might cause these errors. Check for known manual changes before reverting.

Reverting to original will fix the issue.

Comment: I tried reverting the file to its original. Still, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` from your repository and one from the Magento website. Can you please confirm if you are using CE 1.9.1.0 version ?

Comment: Issue got fixed.!
I've updated Mage_Core Version in Config.xml asper the PATCH file. Then PATCH got applied successfully.
Thanks @nikin for your answer.

Comment: Great! . Can you upvote my answer if possible.